# How to query multiple nodes/references in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 nodes, `user_account_settings` and `users`. I want to write a query to get both nodes child where both nodes username is equal. I write a query but it is returning null. How to write a multi reference query.

Data Structure:

[image]

ViewModel Class:

```
private val databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .orderByChild("username")
        .equalTo("faisal.askani")

    private val liveData = FirebaseQueryLiveData(databaseRef)
```

ProfileFramgnet:

```
viewModel.getDataSnapshotLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  Observer { dataSnapshot ->
            if(dataSnapshot != null)
            {
                for (ds: DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
                {
                    //user node
                    if (ds.key.equals("users"))
                    {
                        val user = ds.getValue(User::class.java)
                        viewModel.setUserInfo(user!!)
                    }

                    if(ds.key.equals("user_account_settings"))
                    {
                        val userAccountInfo = ds.getValue(UserAccountSettings::class.java)
                        viewModel.setUserAccountInfo(userAccountInfo!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to write a multi reference query?

There is no way you can perform a "multi reference query". You can get results only from a location that the query is run against, including all the children. In your particular case, you need to use two separate queries, once to get the user detalis and second to get the account details.

It's true that you can add a listener on your root reference and get all the children in the entire database but this is not an option since you'll need to download the content of your entire database, which is a waste of bandwidth and resources.